# Multiclass - spellcasting prerequisite on feat

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, multi-classing, feat-qualifications

I have a multiclass Rogue (Inquisitive) 11 / Wizard (Diviner) 2.
I'd like to take a feat instead of an ASI on my Rogue level 12, but the feat has spellcasting as a prerequisite.
So my question is simply - does the spellcasting of my wizard part allow me to take a feat which requires spellcasting as my rogue level 12 feat, or would I need to use one of the Wizards ASI/feats for that instead?

(Specifically, I'm thinking about taking Eldritch Adept to gain the Devils Sight invocation.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Yes, this works.

The prerequisite for Eldritch Adept is:

> Spellcasting or Pact Magic feature

This is referring to the class feature named Spellcasting. A wizard gains the feature named  Spellcasting at 1st level, so you meet the requirements for the feat by virtue of having at least one class level in Wizard. You may select the feat at any level where you gain the ASI feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can take that feat while leveling any class, your character is already an spellcaster.

According to the DMG Errata:

> If the prerequisite is a class, a creature must be a member of that
> class to attune to the item. If the prerequisite is to be a
> spellcaster, a creature qualifies if it can cast at least one spell
> using its traits or features, not using a magic item or the like.

This means that having the ability to cast spells, any at all, makes a character an spellcaster. Just having racial spells would work for this, like a High Elf cantrip or a Tiefling's Infernal Heritage trait.

Your character, as a level 2 Wizard has the spellcasting feature and is able to cast spells, so there is no impediment to get that feat.

Comment: You’re quoting the DMG rules for the prerequisite “be a spellcaster”, but it’s not relevant to this question because the Eldritch Adept feat’s prerequisite is much more specifically the “Spellcasting or Pact Magic” features. For example a High Elf or Tiefling always qualifies “as a spellcaster”, but only characters with classes that grant the specific features mentioned can take Eldritch Adept.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie my bad! I really thought I was helping there ^^

Comment: well I’m probably being a bit harsh to say it’s not relevant - the questioner is asking about the general case, then specifying they are thinking of Eldritch Adept, which is a specific case. So maybe just add a bit to the end of the answer to clarify that your main point is for feats with the prerequisite “is a spellcaster”, but that Eldritch Adept is a special, more specific case? Then it’s a great, complete answer!